# How to assess files on the Windows 10 IOT when the microSD card his plugged into your computer?

Tags: permissions, raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core, file-access

I am using the windows 10 IOT with a raspberry pi and I can access the pictures I have taken with the portal. However whenever I try and access/find the pictures when reading the SD card on my laptop I cant access/find the folders.

I would just download the images once by one but there's over 500.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which folders do your images locate?

Comment: do you want access it from code or just file explorer?
if the second one is which you want, you can easily use this pattern :
```\\<IPAddress>\c$``` then fill username and password of your windows Iot in the login dialog.

Answer (score 1):

first of all your pi is connected the router.

if yes then follow the following steps.

1:open file manager

2:open any drive and type the following line in path-

\your pi address\$c

now press enter

now you can access the pi with pc